# Forma correta de importar um projeto que está no GitHub

Tags: eclipse, maven, github

Tenho um projeto da faculdade hospedado no GitHub, [neste link](https://github.com/CBSIUFAC/Monitoria), mas no projeto eu só fiz o push para o GitHub dos arquivos das entidades, que foram criados até agora, não fiz push do projeto inteiro, arquivos de configuração etc. Agora quero importar esse projeto para minha segunda máquina. Se eu importar diretamente ele não vem com todo o archetype do Maven, ele vem só um projeto comum. Minha alternativa foi criar um projeto do Maven, e depois importar o projeto que está no GitHub (Ficam dois projetos diferentes) e então copiar os pacotes de um para o outro. Minha dúvida é, saber se tem alguma forma de eu importar isso direto, sem ter que fazer essa gambiarra. Por exemplo, só criar um projeto no Maven e já importar diretamente para ele.

Estou usando o Eclipse Luna EE, Com o Git e o Maven, já instalados no nele.

Comment: Por `archetype do Maven` você quer dizer o pom.xml? Se sim, saiba que ele nao foi commitado, portanto nao tem como voce clonar o repositorio e esperar que ele apareca. Um possivel problema é que voce mavenizou depois de commitar (ou talvez foi outro problema, não sei, nos dê mais detalhes).

Comment: @Math, porque archetype me refiro ao pom.xml e toda a estrutura de pastas que ele cria, no caso criei um webapp-archetype. No caso eu mavenizei antes de comittar, mas não quis comittar os arquivos de configuração por questão de segurança, receio de alguém poder vir causar algum problema e tal sacou? (sou novo com esse negócio de GitHub)  No caso então, só se eu upar todos os arquivos de configuração? Ou ou o pom.xml?

Comment: No caso o que eu queria saber tem como é tipo assim: Eu criar um projeto do maven normal aqui no meu computador (onde ainda não tem o projeto que está no github), Ai importar diretamente pra dentro desse projeto que criei, a pasta que tá no github.

Comment: Se você tem um repositório que não pode ser público te recomendo usar o [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.com) ao invés do GitHub. No BitBucket você pode criar repositórios privados gratuitamente, algo que não é possível no GitHub. A partir daí você pode commitar qualquer tipo de informação que considere sensitiva, pois somente você terá acesso ao repositório . Commite todos os arquivos de configuração + o pom.xml que estará tudo certo.

Comment: Hmmm, ok então. Irei upar no git mesmo os arquivos, pois não posso usar outro serviço, já que é uma matéria da faculdade e o professor exige o GitHub, mas vou ver os arquivos que contém algum tipo de senha para não postar.

Comment: @JoãoNeto, também tive problemas semelhantes quando eu fiz meu projeto de TCC. A solução que eu fiz para manter a estrutura de pastas foi criar arquivos dentro de cada pasta (webapp, resources, main, test).
O `Git` não realiza versionamento de diretórios, apenas de arquivos. Portanto, se não tem nada no diretório, o git não vai reconhecer normalmente.

Comment: normalmente eu faço um Makefile para configurar/testar todo o projeto, funciona como um montador, no git você so deixa o que você desenvolve, o makefile deve baixar e configurarar todas as variaveis de ambiente/senhas/ e libs extras.